# Python 2.7 : How to track declining RAM?

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pandas, memory, pyqt

Data is updated every 5 min. Every 5 min a python script I wrote is run. This data is related to signals, and when the data says a signal is True, then the signal name is shown in a PyQt Gui that I have.

In other words, the Gui is always on my screen, and every 5 min its "main" function is triggered and the "main" function's job is to check the database of signals against the newly downloaded data. I leave this GUI open for hours and days at a time and the computer always crashes. Random python modules get corrupted (pandas can't import this or numpy can't import that) and I have to reinstall python and all the packages.

I have a hypothesis that this is related to the program being open for a long time and using up more and more memory which eventually crashes the computer when the memory runs out.

How would I test this hypothesis? If I can just show that with every 5-min run the available memory decreases, then it would suggest that my hypothesis might be correct.

Here is the code that reruns the "main" function every 5 min:

```
class Editor(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    # my app


def main():
    app   = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex    = Editor()

    milliseconds_autocheck_frequency = 300000 # number of milliseconds in 5 min

    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(ex.run)
    timer.start(milliseconds_autocheck_frequency)

sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```